# executing Kendo command from js console - fails silently

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

If I put the following code block at the end of my HTML page, I see a nice KendoUI colorpicker:

```
$("#tail").kendoFlatColorPicker({
    preview: false,
    value: "#000"
});
```

However, if I instead execute the code from the Javascript console after the page is loaded, it fails silently to do anything.

I guess I have a fundamental misunderstanding about how Kendo does it's stuff (I was expecting similar behaviour to ExtJS - which executes from the console).   Can anyone explain the difference that leads to this behaviour?

EDIT:
Here is the full source (that works, unless I execute the script from the console)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
</style>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="example">
        <div id="tail" class="picker"></div>
    </div>
<script>
$("#tail").kendoFlatColorPicker({
    preview: false,
    value: "#000" 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can run this code in the console on http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/introduction using `$("#welcome-to-kendo-ui")` and it creates a color picker as expected.

Comment: I had no problem running the code in the console and creating the colorpicker after making a local file using your code. Are you perhaps trying to do this on jsfiddle? It won't work since jsfiddle puts your document in a frame that the console can't access.

Comment: No, I'm doing it in the console on Chrome 46.0.2490.86  May I ask what browser you're using?

Comment: Windows, Chrome 46.0.2490.86. Here's a test site: http://infinitry.net/stackoverflow/console.html . If I run `$("#tail").kendoFlatColorPicker({
    preview: false,
    value: "#000" 
});` the colorpicker comes up. Do you get a jQuery object returned at least when you run it? Here's an image of my browser http://i.imgur.com/SQOLf49.png

Comment: thanks heaps for your patience - you've helped me find the issue I had